# ionic2 template: Each list item (main page) connect to tabs structure page

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I ran into a tricky situation:

In my ionic2 app, I have a to-do list Home page which list workflows that are waiting for approval. Every of my workflow item can call a function to navigate to a tabs root page to view workflow details as below:

```
// HomePage:
    selectItem(workflow){
        this.nav.push(TabsPage, workflow);
    }

// my HomePage view 
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      My to-do list
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="logOut()">
        <ion-icon name="log-out"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let w of wfList | async" (click)="selectItem(w)">
      <h3>{{w.case.name}} </h3>

      <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-dropright-outline" item-right></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

My tabs root contains 3 different pages. (every workflow information categorized into 3 tabs).

```
//TabsPage:
tab1Root: any = PageA;
tab2Root: any = PageB;
tab3Root: any = PageC;

//Tabs Html

  <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-title>
        TabsRoot
      </ion-title>

    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="PageA" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="PageB" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="PageC" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

In my pageA, I have an "Approval" button. If the user approve the workflow, I show a toast message then I want to pop back to my to-do list. (My Home page).

```
// PageA:
approve(id){
    this.wf.changeStatus(id).then(() => {
        this.navCtrl.pop();  <- error
    });
  }
```

Everything works fine, except when I tried to pop back, I receive an error message:

```
 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): false
```

I tried to use `popTo(HomePage)` and `popAll()`, but I got the same result. used `popRoot()` will go back to the tab root page with no contents in there. If I use `setRoot(HomePage)` will go back to the Home page but the navbar still have the "back arrow" there.

Can anyone please help?  Thank you very much !

Your system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.10 
OS: OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.9.5
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

Below is my element layout:

HomePage -> TabRoot (include PageA, PageB and PageC).  HomePage is the parent page of Tabs.

Comment: When you run `this.navCtrl.pop()` does the app go back but throw the error, or does it not even go back? Also, can you let me know which exact version of Ionic 2 are you using? If you don't know, just run `ionic info` on the CLI and the version is right after where it says "Ionic Framework Version:".

Comment: Thank you:-) the app threw an error message and won't go back.  Below is my ionic info:
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.10 
OS: OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.9.5
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002

Comment: OK, now on your HomePage class, you've the `selectItem()` method, is that method called by the tabs to change the "current tab" I suppose?

Comment: No. the selectItem() function only called from HomePage view (the html of HomePage).  <ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let w of wfList | async" (click)="selectItem(w)">  (every workflow item all have detail info in 3 tabs).

Comment: OK, can you update your question adding the full HTML of your HomePage template? I think I've an answer for you.

Comment: updated.. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Try adding the full HTML (without mixing it with the TypeScript code) as the HTML you posted doesn't include the markup for the actual tabs...

Comment: Sorry. My home page is not part of tabs pages. home page is the parent page. I also updated the entire home page view there.

Comment: Maybe you can debug (simple console.log) and see if your code does reaches inside the`.then(()...)` portion or gets stuck at `this.wf.changeStatus(id)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found my own answer.  Thanks to Djamware for the hint.

in my HomePage, I called nav.push(TabsRoot); which put the TabRoot on top my HomePage.

In my TabsRoot, I have 3 sub-pages, they all have the same RootPage, which is the TabsRoot page.

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="PageA" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="PageB" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="PageC" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

So, from PageA(or B or C), the sub-page of tabsroot page, need to go back to the rootPage first. Then from the rootPage, I do `tabsRoot.pop()`, which will go back to HomePage

```
// PageA.ts
import { App, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public app: App) {
    .....
}
approve(id){
   this.wf.changeStatus(id).then(() => {
            let tabsRoot = this.app.getRootNav();
            tabsRoot.pop(); 
   });
}
```

Again, thank you everyone here trying to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate from Tab (item of Tabs), you should go to the root of Tabs. Here's example.

```
let nav = this.app.getRootNav();
nav.setRoot(AnotherPage);
```

You can find the problem with tabs in [my tutorial](https://www.djamware.com/post/587d543080aca723c115beaf/how-to-mixing-side-menu-and-tabs-in-ionic-2).

Answer (score 0):

OK, after analyzing your code it seems the problem is you're putting the tabs inside a subpage (TabsRoot), whose parent is HomePage. However, tabs need to go in the root page (i.e. HomePage).

So, try moving your tabs HTML markup and code to the HomePage (root), and it should work.